# Best-fit plane for a set of points

Tags: fitting, curve-fitting

I have a set of 3D points, ie: $P\{(x_1, y_1, z_1), ..., (x_N, y_N, z_N)\}$. Each point in the set is a stellar object, and the $(x,y,z)$ system is defined from their [equatorial coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equatorial_coordinate_system) and distances $(\alpha, \delta, d)$, as:

$$x = f(\alpha, \delta, d)\\
y = g(\alpha, \delta, d)\\
z = D_0 - h(\alpha, \delta, d)
$$

as given in Eq. 5 [here](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2001AJ....122.1807V). The $D_0$ value is the distance to the origin of the $(x,y,z)$ system.

I want to find the plane that "best fits" that cloud of points, assuming I know the values of $(\alpha, \delta, d)$, and thus $(x,y,z)$ for each point in the set, for any given $D_0$.

I've come across two methods:

1. Minimizing the [point-plane distance](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html), that is: the sum of the absolute values of the *perpendicular* distance from each point to a given plane.<sup>[1](http://www.nlreg.com/pointplane.htm)</sup>
2. Minimizing the *vertical* (z) distances of the points to a given plane.<sup>[2](http://www.nlreg.com/plane3d.htm)</sup>

What is the difference between these methods? Is one recommended over the other? Are there any caveats I should be aware of when using either of them?

Comment: Because the answer depends on what the coordinates mean and why you're doing this fit, could you edit this question to include that contextual information?

Comment: There's really not a short answer for that whuber. I'm doing the fit because I need to find the plane equation that "best" represents that set of points. Is there some specific properties of the coordinates that would determine the answer?

Comment: Yes. After all, if you're going to distinguish one of the three coordinates (which you have elected to call "Z") from the other two, then there must be something different about it.  But what?

Comment: Oh I see, of course that makes sense. I'll give more details, trying to be as concise but detailed as possible.

Comment: I've added more details to the problem @whuber, let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: It depends on how accurate you need that plane to be.  For the best results you ought to incorporate information about the measurement errors in $a$, $\delta$, and $d$.  They translate (via the nonlinear formulas for $x,y,z$) into correlated, varying errors in the point locations, which in turn indicate how best to weight those points for the fitting procedure. I can't say any more because I cannot find any "Eq 5" in your reference: it has only four numbered formulas that I can find.

Comment: I meant "formula" 5, where the transformation from the $(\alpha, \delta, D)$ coordinates to the $(x,y,z)$ system is shown.